# How to make this MySQL query sort groups/messages like imessage?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code that will display all chat message groups and messages ORDERED BY when the group was created.

I am trying to instead order the messagegroup list by the last message received instead (exactly how imessage or any text message works)

You have no messages at this time.

```
    <div id="messagegroups">
       <?php while($row_messages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_messages)){ ?>
       <?php
       $snm = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM message_group WHERE group_id = '$row_messages[group_id]' ORDER BY id DESC");
       $rm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($snm);
       $nm = mysqli_num_rows($snm);

       $ur = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$rm[recipients]' ORDER BY id DESC;");
       $rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ur);

       $um = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE group_id = '$row_messages[group_id]' ORDER BY id DESC;");
       $rrr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($um);

       ?>
       <div id="messagegroupholder">
        <div class="qo cj ca js-msgGroup groupclick" id="msg" data-id="<?php echo $rm['group_id']; ?>">
             <a class="b">
              <div class="qf">
                <span class="qj">
                <img class="cu qh" src="./img/<?php echo $rr['image']; ?>" style="height: 42px; width: 42px;">
                </span>
                <div class="qg">
                  <strong><?php echo $rr['username']; ?></strong> and <strong><?php echo $nm - 1 ?> others</strong>
                  <div class="aof">
                    <?php echo substr($rrr['message'], 0, 60); ?> &hellip;
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          </div>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

    </div>

MySQL Structure:

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `messages`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `message` text NOT NULL,
      `ipaddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `group_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=318 ;

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `message_group`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message_group` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `recipients` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `group_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `ipaddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=82 ;

    --
    -- Table structure for table `users`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `user_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `image` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default.png',
      `profile_background` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default_background.png',
      `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `went_to_school` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `worked_at` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `lives_in` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `from_originally` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `expires` datetime NOT NULL,
      `ipaddress` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `browser` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n/a',
      `show_email` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Here is a preview of how the data is stored: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TLt9.jpg

So how can I instead order the message_groups by the last message received instead of when the last group was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you can do a MAX() and GROUP BY to get the latest timestamp for each group_id like

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) as latestTimeStamp,group_id
FROM messages
GROUP BY group_id
```

Then you could call that inner query table as M having the latestTimeStamp and INNER JOIN that with message_groups like

```
SELECT MG.*,M.latestTimeStamp
FROM message_groups MG
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT MAX(timestamp) as latestTimeStamp,group_id
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY group_id)as M
ON MG.group_id = M.group_id
ORDER BY M.latestTimeStamp DESC
```

Comment: Nice! I added another GROUP BY group_id to get this working correctly. You da man. Here is my completed query: SELECT MG.*,M.latestTimeStamp
FROM message_group MG
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(timestamp) as latestTimeStamp,group_id
FROM messages
GROUP BY group_id)as M
ON MG.group_id = M.group_id
WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'
OR recipients = '$_SESSION[username]'
GROUP BY group_idORDER BY M.latestTimeStamp DESC